# spring destroy-method + request scope bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So I wanted to do something like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;

    @PreDestroy 
    public void afterRequest() {
        try {
            System.out.println("After request...");
            // use request here:
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Completed successfully...");
        }
    }
}
```

And I end up with the following message, AFTER the "Completed successfully..." message logs:

> 09:19:16 WARN  Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.myBean': java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

I'm not really sure what to make of this, since my logging indicates the destroy method completed successfully. Does anyone know what's going on?

EDIT:
Here's the `mvc-servlet.xml`. As you can see there is not much going on here. It's all annotation driven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<!-- properties file -->
<context:property-placeholder location="app.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.web" />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.services" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view" p:suffix=".jspx" />
</beans>
```

Comment: I noticed that DisposableBeanAdapter implements Runnable....does it run inside a thread? That would kind of explain the error message, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528444/accessing-scoped-proxy-beans-within-threads-of. However it doesn't completely make sense since the error shows up *after* my method has executed.

Comment: show the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: everything (almost) is annotation config driven, but I'll attach anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get this working, but I ended up changing the code to apply @After advice on the controller methods, which has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use request scope without spring MVC you should declare `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` in web-app  listener.

```
<web-app>
  ...
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  ...
</web-app>
```

check http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration

Comment: That's not the problem, I guess I wasn't clear. I am using spring MVC.