# Spring Boot, java.lang.IllegalStateException when calling ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo from a websocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-boot

I'm getting the following error when calling `ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo` from a websocket.

```java
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.getCurrentRequest(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:234)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.getBuilder(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:186)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.java:117)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:135)
    at urlshortener2014.common.web.UrlShortenerController.createAndSaveIfValid(UrlShortenerController.java:94)
    at urlshortener2014.richcarmine.web.UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs.access$200(UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs.java:45)
    at urlshortener2014.richcarmine.web.UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs$CreateCallable.call(UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs.java:226)
    at urlshortener2014.richcarmine.massiveShortenerNaiveWS.ShortURLWSGenerator.onCall(ShortURLWSGenerator.java:41)
    at urlshortener2014.richcarmine.massiveShortenerNaiveWS.ShortURLWSGenerator.onCall(ShortURLWSGenerator.java:15)
    at urlshortener2014.richcarmine.massiveShortenerREST.RequestContextAwareCallable.call(RequestContextAwareCallable.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The whole project is about shortening urls, as my first approach with spring websockets I'm trying to get it work just by answering back the shortened url from any url.

My `TextWebSocketHandler`

```java
public class MyHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    AtomicLong messageOrder = new AtomicLong(0);
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    CompletionService<CSVContent> pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);

    /* controller reference */
    @Autowired
    UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs controller;

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        logger.info("WS: " + message.getPayload());
        long order = messageOrder.getAndIncrement();
        pool.submit(new ShortURLWSGenerator(order,message.getPayload(),"","","",session.getRemoteAddress(),controller));
        CSVContent content = pool.take().get();
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Echo Test: " + content.getShortURL().getUri()));
    }
}
```

Here is `ShortURLWSGenerator`

```java
public class ShortURLWSGenerator extends RequestContextAwareCallable<CSVContent>{
    ...
    @Override
    public CSVContent onCall() {

        ShortURL shortURL = null;
        try {
            shortURL = controller. new CreateCallable(url,sponsor,brand,owner,address.toString()).call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CSVContent content = new CSVContent();
        content.setOrder(order);
        content.setShortURL(shortURL);

        return content;
    }
}
```

Used [RequestContextAwareCallable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528444/accessing-scoped-proxy-beans-within-threads-of) which solved the same problem when implementing the same functionlity as a REST service, in any case I'm still getting the same error even with a simple Callable.

Here is CreateCallable that just wraps the main function

```java
public class CreateCallable implements Callable<ShortURL>{
    ...
    @Override
    public ShortURL call() throws Exception {
        /* explodes while creating the new short url */
        return createAndSaveIfValid(url,sponsor,brand,owner,ip);
    }
}
```

Finally here is `createAndSaveIfValid`which calls `ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo`

```java
protected ShortURL createAndSaveIfValid(String url, String sponsor,
        String brand, String owner, String ip) {
    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(new String[] { "http",
            "https" });
    if (urlValidator.isValid(url)) {
        String id = Hashing.murmur3_32()
                .hashString(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
        ShortURL su = new ShortURL(id, url,
                linkTo(
                        methodOn(UrlShortenerController.class).redirectTo(
                                id, null)).toUri(), sponsor, new Date(
                        System.currentTimeMillis()), owner,
                HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT.value(), true, ip, null);
        return shortURLRepository.save(su);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The complete project can be found [here on github](https://github.com/SAReyes/UrlShortener2014/tree/master/richCarmine)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On a closely related note, for those unit testing their concrete `ResourceAssemblerSupport` implementations, and experiencing the same stack trace, here's how to mock it out:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    HttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(mockRequest);
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(servletRequestAttributes);
}

@After
public void teardown() {
    RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified to use MockHttpServletRequest and then you don't have to do all that Mockito magic.

`HttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(mockRequest);
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(servletRequestAttributes);`

Comment: Would be also reset `RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes(); ` after tests are done `@AfterClass`

Answer (score 8):

`linkTo` depends on the current HTTP request but the HTTP current request does not exist because the call was originated by a WebSocket event. Therefore you need a different approach.

1. Create a method named e.g. `createAndSaveIfValidExtended` based on `createAndSaveIfValid`. The code is the same but `linkTo(methodOn(UrlShortenerController.class).redirectTo(id, null)).toUri()` is replaced by the method `createLink(id)`
2. Create a method `String createLink(String id)`. This method will build the URL by using a property defined in `application.properties` (see here [how](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)) whose value will be injected in a field that represents where the app will be deployed concatenated with `/l` and the value of `ìd`.
3. In `CreateCallable`, call `createAndSaveIfValidExtended` instead of `createAndSaveIfValid`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an even simpler version of Robert Bain's code that we ended up using in our Spock tests...

```
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequestMock = new MockHttpServletRequest()
    ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(httpServletRequestMock)
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(servletRequestAttributes)
```